# How to save form data to database while needing to prevent form submission due to socket.io?

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, socket.io

Question: I would like to save form input data to mysql database, but socket.io requires preventdefault so I cant figure out the best way to use socket.io and save the data.

I have form with ~10 input fields that I have been submitting as a post request and then saving to a mysql database using my express app.

Before:

```
**index.ejs**
<form class='form' role='form' action='/users' method='POST'>
  <input class='form-input' name='Client[FName]' type='text' />
  <input class='form-input' name='Client[LName]' type='text' />
  etc..
</form>

**server.js**
router.post('/users', (req, res) => {
  const post = req.body.Client
    pool.query('INSERT INTO Client SET ?', post, (err, result) => {
     res.redirect(`users/${result.insertId}`);
  })
})
```

Everything was working great until I was then asked to use socket.io so that I could update another page in real time with information submitted by the form. In order to use socket.io I had to prevent the default form submission:

```
**index.js**
let form = document.querySelector('.form');
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  socket.emit('message', {
    FName: inputs[0].value,
    LName: inputs[1].value,
    etc,
    etc
  })
})

**server.js**
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
 socket.on('message', (message) => {
  socket.broadcast.emit('message', message)

   *sql insert statement here??*

 })
});
```

The socket.io is working great, and I am updating the DOM in real time, but now I need to figure out how to get back to saving the data to mysql again. Is there any way to do this other than setting a timeout in the event listener? Should I just insert my previous query into the socket.io function?

I apologize for the winded question, and thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm, why not just make the POST to /users in the server.js code?

Answer (score 0):

Two options i can think of

1) Make the POST to /users inside server.js when you get the message from the client

2) Make an ajax POST to /users inside the index.js submit handler e.g.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  socket.emit('message', {
    FName: inputs[0].value,
    LName: inputs[1].value,
    ...
  });
  $.post({
    url: "/users",
    ...

   });
})
```